# How to restore default layout for intellij Run/Debug window/tabs?

Tags: intellij-idea

I accidentally closed the Debugger tab of the Run/Debug panel. Then while attempting to restore it other changes were made that I would like to revert. How to get back to square one?

[image]

Comment: Off of memory, isn't there are "Window" button in the top task bar? To restore the debugger window, you could have gone into view->tools(or something like that)-> debugger, then drag it back into the bar.

Comment: The one above the gear, if you hover over it, it will tell you "Restore Layout" :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

After clicking on basically every icon on all sides of the panel: it's the "Restore Layout" icon on the left side:

[image]

Answer (score 31):

The icon is below on the left and if it is hovered, 'Restore Layout' is displayed.[image]

Above a screen shot of the icon to 'restore visual elements of debugger session to default state' (the icon is surrounded by a yello frame).